# I cannot change the order of result columns in Windows Desktop Search 4.0 under Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, windows-search

I cannot change the order of result columns in Windows Desktop Search 4.0 under Windows XP.

When I searched the web for how to do it, I found comments that under Windows Vista you could right-click the headers of the columns and tick them according to your needs or just drag them to the place you want, afterwards saving folder settings....

In my Windows XP I can tick columns and rearrange them in normal folders but any change to the columns in the Windows Desktop Search window seems prohibited. Nothing changeable.

Is that by design or is there a workaround?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think it's possible on XP. Windows Desktop Search does not open in a regular Explorer window, although it looks similar to a "normal" folder.